# UItableviewcontroller as popup not showing data

Tags: uitableview, swift2, uipopovercontroller

I want to show UITableViewController as popup on button press. I am able to show popup using this code

```
  let menuViewController =  popTableViewController() //popTableViewController

    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 132)
    //menuViewController.tableView = FrontTable

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    presentViewController(
        menuViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
```

but it is showing blank table view in popup. I have also added the content in tableview class but it not showing any reflection on result.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code in your UIViewController

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
return .None
}
```

Comment: Try below answer with your tableViewControllerName at breedPopover and its storyboard id in "storyboar_id"

Answer (score 0):

or you can try below code to create popover

```
let  mpopover = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("breedPop") as! breedPopover
mpopover.delegate = self
self.citiesPopover = mpopover
citiesPopover!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
citiesPopover!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)


let popoverPresentationViewController = citiesPopover!.popoverPresentationController
popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self
popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceView = breedTextField
popoverPresentationViewController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(breedTextField.frame.width, breedTextField.frame.height*3, 0, 0)
    presentViewController(citiesPopover!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank You, is was my mistake in code. Now it is working but app is crashing on  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("roomcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RoomsViewTableViewCell , do you have any idea

Comment: set tableView delegate & dataSource to self in viewDidLoad()